# React-native Bugsnag Breadcrumbs

Tags: react-native, breadcrumbs, bugsnag

breadcrumbs work fine if I only pass a type but throw an error when I attempt to pass additional data:

```
client.leaveBreadcrumb(msg, {
  type: 'navigation',
  component: 'Something',
  props: props,
  previousScene: 'Previous',
});
```

Any thoughts on why this would be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the type definition of the `leaveBreadcrumb` function:

```
public leaveBreadcrumb(name: string, metadata?: IMetadata | string): void;
```

You see that is the allowed parameters are `name` and `metadata`. So you cannot add arbitrary parameters.

`metadata` is an object of key-value pairs with an optional `type` field, i.e. it's type definition looks as follows:

```
export interface IMetadata {
  type?:
    | "error"
    | "log"
    | "navigation"
    | "process"
    | "request"
    | "state"
    | "user"
    | "manual";
  [key: string]: IMetadataValue | string | number | boolean | undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Bugsnag's [latest React Native docs](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/react-native/react-native/customizing-breadcrumbs/#attaching-metadata), you can see there are 3 fields for leaving a custom breadcrumb.

I would modify your code to the following:

```
Bugsnag.leaveBreadcrumb(msg, {
  component: 'Something',
  props: props,
  previousScene: 'Previous'
}, 
 'navigation'
);
```